# SQL statement (Order by)

Tags: java, mysql

I need to order my data by the latest date.

This SQL statment is **working**

```
final String selectSql = "select * from questionnaire where userprofileid=" + userProfileID ;
```

This SQL statment is ** **NOT working****

```
final String selectSql = "select * from questionnaire where userprofileid=" + userProfileID +"ORDER by datecreated desc";
```

> Error Message: 
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by datecreated desc' at line 1

Comment: Aside from the space problem other answers have pointed out, please don't build SQL dynamically like this. Use parameterized queries instead, which will help avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a space before ORDER:

```
final String selectSql = "select * from questionnaire where userprofileid=" + userProfileID +" ORDER by datecreated desc";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try leave a space before ORDER BY. `" ORDER BY datecreated desc"`

Comment: @AnneMahLi'en please  accept some previously answered questions to improve your rate.

Answer (score 1):

The final string should look like this:

```
final String selectSql = "select * 
                          from questionnaire 
                          where userprofileid=" + userProfileID + 
                          " ORDER by datecreated desc"; // add a space
                                                        // after the double 
                                                        // quote
```